# Unable to get this.value in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, this, onchange

```
function showData(){
  Object.keys(JSONcall).forEach(function(key){
    var tvShow = JSONcall[key].show;
    $('#show-select').append("<option class=\"selectS\"" + 
      "id=\"" + key + "\"" + "value=\"JSONcall[" + key + "]
      .show\" onchange=\"selectShow(this.id)\">" + tvShow.name + "</option>");
  });
}
```

Hello, I have this `forEach` loop where the function is to append the results of a JSON object. After appending the result is:

```
<option class="selectS" id="0" value="JSONcall[0].show" 
   onchange="selectShow(this.id)">Some Value</option>
```

First question: Is it wise to append `onchange=(function())` like that?

`selectShow(value)` is a function meant to get id of `<option>` and display the data in another `<div>`.

Last question is why am I unable to get the results of `this.id` in this context?

Comment: you might want to use onchange attribute on the select element in combination with [selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex)

Comment: can you try out suggestion

Comment: is that worked for you ??

Comment: You can also use `$('.someClass').data()` to attatch & retrieve data from the element without having to store data in multiple places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create option element like this , and three is no need of `id` at option element as you are having `val` on `option` to identify it.

```
$('<option>').val(key).text(tvShow.name).appendTo('#show-select');
```

one more thing `selectShow()` must need to apply at to `select` not to option.

```
<select onchange= "selectShow()"> </select>

function selectShow(){
  console.log($( "#show-select" ).val());
}
```

Comment: reason for - 1?

Comment: @fupuchu - what you expect as id valye ...? and can you provide structure of you object

Comment: Ah yes, it works now, like you said selectShow() should be assinged to <select> not <option>.

Answer (score 1):

I have reworked your code in a different way.

- Used `$.ajax()` to pull some random JSON data and parse it.
- Used `$.each(var, function(index, value) {})` to iterate over the object.
- Used `change()` event to log `text`, `val`, `id`

The rest you can modify inside `append()` method.

```js
function showData() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bHepFCoNmG?indent=2",
    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, (i, val) => {
        $("#mySelect").append('<option class="selectS" id="' + i + '" value="' + val.name + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
      });
    }
  });
}

// change event
$('#mySelect').change(function() {
  console.log($(this).find(':selected').text());
  console.log($(this).find(':selected').val());
  console.log($(this).find(':selected').attr("id"));
});

showData();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="mySelect">
  
  </select>
</div>
```

---

The code below shows how to use [`jQuery.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) to solve the same issue:

```js
//TODO: Add triggers and events

function showData() {
 // Retrieve JSON file from website
  $.ajax({
   
    // Returns 15 rows
    url: "https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cuScfPsQRK?indent=2",
    success: function(data) {
    
     // Iterate retrieved JSON Object
      $.each(data, (i, val) => {

        // Get JSON keys
        let key   = val.key;
        let value = val.value;

        // Define metadata object
        let metaData = JSON.stringify({
          index : i,
          key   : key,
          value : value
        })

        // Create template & pass configuration object
        $('<option></option>', {
          id          : i,
          text        : key,
          value       : value,
          class       : "selectS",
          'data-meta' : metaData
        }).appendTo('#mySelect');
      });
    }
  });
}

$('#mySelect').change(function() {
 // Get data('meta') keys
  let index = $(this).find(':selected').data('meta').index;
  let key   = $(this).find(':selected').data('meta').key;
  let value = $(this).find(':selected').data('meta').value;
  
  $("#dataId").text(index);
  $("#dataKey").text(key);
  $("#dataValue").text(value);

  // Using template literals
  //console.log(`================\nID: ${index}\nKey: ${key}\nValue: ${value}\n================`);
});

showData();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Select a Person:</h3>

<hr>

<select id="mySelect">
  
</select>

<hr>

<div id="data">
  Index:
  <span id="dataId">N/A</span><br>
  
  Key:
  <span id="dataKey">N/A</span><br>
  
  Value:
  <span id="dataValue">N/A</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Damn this is neater than what I have.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your `onchange` trigger on your `select`. I advice you to add event with javascript no in html attribute. You have to use `value` instead of `id` for *sharing* value.

```js
const obj = {
  channel1: {
    show: {
      id: "#ch1",
      name: "ch1"
    }
  },
  channel2: {
    show: {
      id: "#ch2",
      name: "ch2"
    }
  }
};

function showData() {
  $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
    const tvShow = value.show; // obj[key] === value
    $("<option></option")
      .addClass("selectS")
      .val(key)
      .text(tvShow.name)
      .appendTo("#show-select");
  });
}

function selectShow() {
  console.log($(this).val());
}

showData();
$("#show-select").on("change", selectShow)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="show-select"></select>
```

Comment: @HorsSuject, ignore the edit, I edited the wrong post. Apologies